# Gettin crossfilter.js error "too much recursion"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

Iam getting error `"too much recursion"` on crossfilter.js How can I fix this error.

Here my javascript codes(I am giving data from php.So data is not wrong.I think dimension error):

```
 var data= [{
          HASTANE: 'ANK',
          SEHIR: 'Ankara',
          BOLGE: 'İç Anadolu Bölgesi ',
          KOD: 'C00',
          KODACIKLAMA: 'Dudağın habis neoplazması',
          KURUM: 'Devlet' , 
          DONEM: 'OCAK 2014',
          SAYI: 2, 
          INSIDANS:2
        },{
          HASTANE: 'TKD',
          SEHIR: 'Tekirdağ',
          BOLGE: 'Marmara Bölgesi ',
          KOD: 'C00',
          KODACIKLAMA: 'Dudağın habis neoplazması',
          KURUM: 'Devlet' , 
          DONEM: 'OCAK 2014',
          SAYI: 1, 
          INSIDANS:1
        },{
          HASTANE: 'ADN',
          SEHIR: 'Adana',
          BOLGE: 'Akdeniz Bölgesi',
          KOD: 'C00',
          KODACIKLAMA: 'Dudağın habis neoplazması',
          KURUM: 'Devlet' , 
          DONEM: 'OCAK 2014',
          SAYI: 1, 
          INSIDANS:1
        },{
          HASTANE: 'ESKYM',
          SEHIR: 'Eskişehir',
          BOLGE: 'İç Anadolu Bölgesi ',
          KOD: 'C00',
          KODACIKLAMA: 'Dudağın habis neoplazması',
          KURUM: 'Devlet' , 
          DONEM: 'OCAK 2014',
          SAYI: 1, 
          INSIDANS:1
        },{
          HASTANE: 'IST',
          SEHIR: 'İstanbul',
          BOLGE: 'Marmara Bölgesi ',
          KOD: 'C00',
          KODACIKLAMA: 'Dudağın habis neoplazması',
          KURUM: 'Devlet' , 
          DONEM: 'OCAK 2014',
          SAYI: 2, 
          INSIDANS:2
        }] 

var mapChart = dc.bubbleOverlay("#map").svg(d3.select("#map svg"));
 var donemRowMapChart = dc.rowChart("#donem-map-chart");
 var bolgeRowMapChart = dc.rowChart("#bolge-map-chart");


        var d= [data];
        var data = crossfilter(d);

        var sehir=data.dimension(function(d){return d.SEHIR;});
        var donem=data.dimension(function(d){return d.DONEMADI;});
        var bolge=data.dimension(function(d){return d.BOLGE;});

        var sehirGroup=sehir.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.INSIDANS});
        var donemGroup=donem.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.INSIDANS});
        var bolgeGroup=bolge.group().reduceSum(function(d){return d.INSIDANS});

        mapChart.width(600)
                .height(450)
                .dimension(sehir)
                .group(sehirGroup)
                .radiusValueAccessor(function(p) {
                    return p.value;
                })
                .r(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200000]))
                .colors(["#ff7373","#ff4040","#ff0000","#bf3030","#a60000"])
                .colorDomain([13, 30])
                .colorAccessor(function(p) {
                    return p.value;
                })
                .title(function(d) {
                    return "City: " + d.key
                            + "\nINSIDANS SAYISI: " +d.value;
                })
                .point("TR.GA", 364, 400)
                .point("TR.ED", 395.5, 383)
                .debug(false);

 donemRowMapChart
                .width(300)
                .height(200)
                .margins({top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
                .dimension(donem)
                .group(donemGroup)
                .colors(d3.scale.category10())
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().ticks(4);   

 bolgeRowMapChart
                .width(300)
                .height(200)
                .margins({top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20})
                .dimension(bolge)
                .group(bolgeGroup)
                .colors(d3.scale.category10())
                .elasticX(true)
                .xAxis().ticks(4);                              

    dc.renderAll();
```

Error raising on line 178,col 4 crossfilter.js :

```
function quicksort(a, lo, hi) {
    // Compute the two pivots by looking at 5 elements.
    var sixth = (hi - lo) / 6 | 0,
        i1 = lo + sixth,
        i5 = hi - 1 - sixth,
        i3 = lo + hi - 1 >> 1,  // The midpoint.
        i2 = i3 - sixth,
        i4 = i3 + sixth;

........................}
```

So How can I fix thiis error.

Thanks For Helps

Comment: Please show your data.  Also, which line of code is raising the error?

Comment: I updated question.Please look at again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this happens to me when I have dimensions that are not naturally ordered. You'll usually want to cast any value that you use to make a dimension. Specifically, DONEMADI may not be a property on many of your data objects as it doesn't appear in your sample data. I'd change your code to

```
var sehir=data.dimension(function(d){return "" + d.SEHIR;});
var donem=data.dimension(function(d){return "" + d.DONEMADI;});
var bolge=data.dimension(function(d){return "" + d.BOLGE;});

var sehirGroup=sehir.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d.INSIDANS});
var donemGroup=donem.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d.INSIDANS});
var bolgeGroup=bolge.group().reduceSum(function(d){return +d.INSIDANS});
```

Do you still see the problem if you do this?

Comment: Yes.I missied DONEMADI.Ichanged as DONEM.But Now I am getting "p is undefined" on line "return p.value.INSIDANS;" in mapChart

Comment: Shouldn't it just be p.value?